# Comparator class displays wrong sorting

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have a list populated with DMatch object, this object contains attribute "distance".

what i want to do is to sort that list ascendingly or desceningly according to the "distance".

in the below code i used Comparator class and sorte dthe list desceingly, but he output of the index (8, 9,10, 11) are not sorted well.

please let me know what i am doing wrong and how to fix this mistake

**Code**:

```
    Collections.sort(list_RawMatchesMatDMatch, ascOrder);
                for (int i = 0; i < list_RawMatchesMatDMatch.size(); i++) {
                    Log.D(TAG, "main", "rawMatDMatchLiat(" + i + ").distance: " + list_RawMatchesMatDMatch.get(i).distance);                        
                }

    static Comparator<DMatch> ascOrder = new Comparator<DMatch>() {

    public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return (int) (arg1.distance - arg0.distance);

    }
};
```

**output**:

```
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(0).distance: 454.26645
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(1).distance: 447.3835
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(2).distance: 442.294
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(3).distance: 438.98862
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(4).distance: 433.11084
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(5).distance: 427.35114
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(6).distance: 426.2335
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(7).distance: 425.16232
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(8).distance: 423.816
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(9).distance: 423.6815
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(10).distance: 424.51855
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(11).distance: 424.66693
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(12).distance: 423.53986
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(13).distance: 423.79712
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(14).distance: 423.62012
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(15).distance: 421.72028
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(16).distance: 419.46274
Debug: MainClass -> main: rawMatDMatchLiat(17).distance: 418.12198
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is no good:

```
return (int) (arg1.distance - arg0.distance);
```

since the int cast will truncate the results. Instead do:

```
if (arg1.distance > arg0.distance) {
    return 1;
} else if (arg1.distance < arg0.distance) {
    return -1;
} else {
   return 0;
}
```

Or better:

```
return Double.compare(arg1.distance, arg0.distance);
```

Comment: bbut why the method "public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1) "is always "int" i tried to make float but that is not possible

Comment: @rmaik: I don't understand your comment -- please explain.

Comment: i mean the return ada type of the method "public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1)" is int, i cant change it

Comment: @rmaik: no you can't, but why would you want to? It can only represent one of 3 states, and its signature is set.

Comment: 3 states?? ii thought they are 2 states, ascending or descending!! which one is the 3rd?

Comment: @rmaik: the compare method can return one of 3 states -- positive, negative or 0. The sorter then uses these results to determine how to sort the items. Your problem was that your method was returning 0 too often due to your casting your result to int.